# Using by with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here I am trying to use the by parameter in the data.table to rank the prediction column within each group.  I haven't been able to understand why the following piece of code isn't working:

```
> x.small
       prediction group
 1: -0.0093753015    up
 2:  0.0204832283  down
 3: -0.0091790179  down
 4: -0.0473988803  down
 5:  0.0144955868  down
 6: -0.0139455871  down
 7:  0.0005746896    up
 8: -0.0174406693  down
 9: -0.0180556244  down
10: -0.0343069464    up
> x.small[, rank(prediction), by=group]
Error in rank(prediction) :
  'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

But this example code works fine:

```
> diamonds.dt <- data.table(diamonds[1:10, c('carat', 'color')])
> diamonds.dt
    carat color
 1:  0.23     E
 2:  0.21     E
 3:  0.23     E
 4:  0.29     I
 5:  0.31     J
 6:  0.24     J
 7:  0.24     I
 8:  0.26     H
 9:  0.22     E
10:  0.23     H
> diamonds.dt[, rank(carat), by=color]
    color  V1
 1:     E 3.5
 2:     E 1.0
 3:     E 3.5
 4:     E 2.0
 5:     I 2.0
 6:     I 1.0
 7:     J 2.0
 8:     J 1.0
 9:     H 2.0
10:     H 1.0
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

Okay now I really have no idea what's going on, this is very bizarre.  I tried making a reproducible example for @Ananda but could not recreate the error.  I even tried running the ranking logic on an exact copy of the prediction column and it worked fine:

```
> x.small[, prediction.copy:=prediction]
> x.small[, rank(prediction.copy), by=group]
    group V1
 1:    up  2
 2:    up  3
 3:    up  1
 4:  down  7
 5:  down  5
 6:  down  1
 7:  down  6
 8:  down  4
 9:  down  3
10:  down  2
> x.small[, rank(prediction), by=group]
Error in rank(prediction) :
  'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

How could there be two different results from two identical columns?

EDIT 2:

Output of dput(x.small):

```
> dput(x.small)
structure(list(prediction = structure(c(-0.00937530151309606,
0.0204832283018108, -0.00917901792827827, -0.0473988802836657,
0.0144955868466372, -0.0139455871394683, 0.000574689607249577,
-0.0174406692627376, -0.0180556244204637, -0.0343069463869563
), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
)), group = c("up", "down", "down", "down", "down", "down", "up",
"down", "down", "up"), prediction.copy = c(-0.00937530151309606,
0.0204832283018108, -0.00917901792827827, -0.0473988802836657,
0.0144955868466372, -0.0139455871394683, 0.000574689607249577,
-0.0174406692627376, -0.0180556244204637, -0.0343069463869563
)), .Names = c("prediction", "group", "prediction.copy"), row.names = c(NA,
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x22f2af8>)
```

Comment: Can you post some reproducible code (or rather, code that reproduces the error you are mentioning)? If I copy and paste your code it works fine for me....

Comment: @Ananda Just posted an update, this is very strange

Comment: Can you edit your question to include `dput(x.small)`.

Comment: The two columns aren't identical: the `x.small$prediction` vector is a named vector (you can see it in the `dput` output, or with `names(x.small$prediction)`). Why does your column have names? Remove them and it solves your problem

Comment: Even this works for me.... What version of "data.table" are you using?

Comment: I see the same error with the `dput`ted data. If you look at `str(x.small)`, you'll see that your original column has names, while the copy, `prediction.copy`, does not. `x.small[,rank(unname(prediction)), by=group]` also works. I won't make this an answer, since I'm not sure why `by` doesn't play nice with names. (data.table 1.8.10 here)

Comment: Thanks so much everyone, would never have caught this otherwise.  Ananda, I'm on version 1.8.8.  Maybe this issue was patched, do you have a later version?

Comment: no error for 1.8.11 - @andrewhannigan upgrade for sure - there are a ton of enhancements since 1.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll just close this one.  If you are having this same issue, check if the problem column is a named vector by running str(x.small) and seeing if the vector starts with the word "Named".  For some reason using the by parameter when operating on a named vector is causing issues.  This appears to be a minor bug in earlier versions of data.table that was patched in later versions.  To fix it, upgrade data.table or just use `unname()` as @Frank suggested:

```
x.small[,rank(unname(prediction)), by=group]
```